# Is there an easy way to copy files from Azure VM?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have a VM and I want to be able to copy a large amount of files to a backup drive. I have remote desktop and tried to copy that way , but the copy halts and gives no error.
The size is about 120G of data ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copying files larger than 2 GB with RDP isn't supported. Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/remote/copying-2-gb-file-by-clipboard-redirection-fails) article for details.

As an alternate option, you could try using the [Azure Backup service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/remote/copying-2-gb-file-by-clipboard-redirection-fails) if you intend to back up your Azure VM. Backups are stored in a Recovery Services vault with built-in management of recovery points. Configuration and scaling are simple, backups are optimized, and you can easily restore as needed.

As part of the backup process, a snapshot is taken, and the data is transferred to the Recovery Services vault with no impact on production workloads. You can also schedule your backups to a suitable time so that resources are optimally used.